# @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) not working on List

Tags: java, json

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
Public class Event{
private int Id;
private String name;
}


    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    Public class EventResponse{
        private List<Event> eventList;

  }
```

In response I am sending the list of events. I am using spring-boot. 
If there is no data with the id in Cassandra, it is returning null.
Response I am getting is

```
"eventList": [
    {
      "event": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Halus"
      }
    },
    {}
]
```

But I am expecting

```
"eventList": [
    {
      "event": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Halus"
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: You had `NON_NULL` in your question and `NON_EMPTY` in your code. Which one are you using exactly?

Comment: Updated.. EMPTY will check both null and empty. I tried both of them. But no luck

Comment: Can you share the parent POJO which has list of Events?

Comment: Added the parent pojo